# Unable to Build and Run Unity VR project for Daydream on phone and having hard time debugging the application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-vr, daydream

Although I’m able to run the apk on phone, but whenever I try to build and run my project directly from Unity on phone, it doesn’t work. This is the error message it shows:[image]

On checking the console, these are the messages it shows:
[image]

But I'm pretty sure my path is correct, I checked it multiple times. Also, the APKs are building and working fine. Let me know how can I Build and Run from Unity as I'm not able to debug the applications.

Comment: Did you updated the Android SDK to the latest version?

Comment: @Ludovic Yep.. Android and JDK all updated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue that is solved by downgrading the Android SDK tools to an older version as reported [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-deployment-error.444133/#post-2876464).

I am just going to re-narrate the steps in the link I shared above for convenience as follows:

- Go to [Android Studio website](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).
- Scroll down to the end of the page and download the command line tools from the section titled as "Get just the command line tools"
- In your computer, go to $AndroidSDKHome$ and rename the tools folder to tools.bak
- Extract the contents of zip file that you downloaded to the $AndroidSDKHome$. This basically will replace your SDK tools folder with a downgraded version.

Comment: What version do you recommend downloading?

Comment: When I had the issue last week, I downloaded the one that is under the section "Get just the command line tools" in the webpage I shared above and things worked fine with Unity 5.6 beta and Google VR SDK 1.4. When I checked the version of my Android SDK tools @ $Android SDK home$/tools/source.properties, I can see that it is 25.2.3.

Comment: Cool.. I downloaded version 25.2.5 and it works fine.

Comment: Do you encounter the device screen turning grey in the APK on running 360 degree videos for long as well?

Comment: No idea about that, sorry.